# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm a newbie at hibernate and I'm trying to test my entities (persistance)
and this error keep showing

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/registry/classloading/spi/ClassLoaderService
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:80)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:71)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:52)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
at Pers.PersistTest.main(PersistTest.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 6 more
```

This is my entity

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
 public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int idUser;
...
private boolean isAdmin;
```

(with getters and setters and constructor of course)

and this is the test class

```
public class PersistTest {
public static void main(String[] args) { 

    EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Session s = new AnnotationConfiguration()  
            .configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();

    User c = new User();
    c.setIdUser(1);
    ...
    c.setAdmin(true);

    em.persist(c);
    t.commit();
    s.close();
    System.out.print("success");
}
```

and this is persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider> 
           <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/GBO1" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
  </properties>
```

and this is my hibernate dependencies

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
<version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>5.0.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
<version>3.3.2.Beta1</version>
</dependency>
```

and thanks in advance :)

Comment: whats with all of the Hibernate-specific Session/Transaction nonsense? JPA does all of that. NoClassDefFound means you either don't have that class or one of its dependents present. And bearing in mind that "hibernate-annotations" hasn't been released in years, perhaps you don't need that at all. I'm sure the Hibernate docs should tell you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You mix a JPA approach (using `EntityMananger`) and a Hibernate `Session` approach.
2. You use Hibernate 3 libraries (3.5.6-Final) and Hibernate 5 `hibernate-entitymanager` (5.0.6.Final).

You can use to getting started

[Hibernate Getting Started Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/quickstart/html/)